# What are the rev00000.dat files?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I've created an application with bitcoinj that extracts all addresses which have been used out of the block chain files created by bitcoin-core.

I'm extracting the transactions only out of the `blk*.dat` files. Do these files really contain any transactions or are there further transaction in the `rev*.dat` files?

What does the `rev*.dat` files contain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are files to assist reversing additions to the blockchain, handling reorganisations. They essentially contain the references needed to quickly **rev**erse a block being accepted and it’s changes being made to the nodes UTXO. It does not contain transactions.